# MYSQL: Create Table If Not Exists

Tags: sql, mysql

If I do a **Create Table If Not Exists**, and a table with the same name exists with fewer rows (or columns), what would happen?

Comment: I assume you mean columns, not rows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The table will not be created if a table with the same name already exists regardless of table layout.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing.  If the "IF Not Exists" clause fails, the rest of the create is skipped.